# How to get days in a month in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, calendar

I have customer UI calendar I have an issue:

For example, September has 30 day start from 01/09/2020->30/09/2020 but UI calendar display from 29/08/2020->02/10/2020

This is my code. Who can help me?

```kotlin
 val calendar: Calendar =  Calendar.getInstance()       
 calendar.firstDayOfWeek = Calendar.MONDAY
 calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, position)
               
 // Set day of month as 1
 calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
               
 // Get a number of the first day of the week
 val dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
               
 // Count when month is beginning
 val firstDayOfWeek = calendar.firstDayOfWeek
 val monthBeginningCell = (if (dayOfWeek < firstDayOfWeek) 7 else 0) + dayOfWeek - firstDayOfWeek
               
 // Subtract a number of beginning days, it will let to load a part of a previous month
 calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -monthBeginningCell)
               
 /* Get all days of one page (35 is a number of all possible cells in one page
 (a part of previous month, current month and a part of next month))
 */
 while (days.size < 35) {
     days.add(calendar.time)
     calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
 }
```

Comment: You may need 4, 5 or 6 weeks. If February has 28 days and begins on a Monday, 4 suffice. If the month has 30 days and begins on a Sunday, you need 6. The same for some 31 days months.

Comment: Yes, It's 5 weeks

Answer (score 0):

What are exactly you need? If you need full range of calendar for one month, you can use below code for example:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        // The month you want to set
        int month = Calendar.SEPTEMBER;
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        int firstDayOfMonth = calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int lastDayOfMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        System.out.println(getTimeOfWeek(lastDayOfMonth, false, month));
        System.out.println(getTimeOfWeek(firstDayOfMonth, true, month));
    }

    private static Instant getTimeOfWeek(int day, boolean isFirst, int month) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        int dayInWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (isFirst) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day - dayInWeek + 1);
        } else {
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day + 7 - dayInWeek);
        }
        return calendar.toInstant();
    }
}
```

If you only want the range on the month, just set the calendar to the first and the last day on that month.
Hope it works!